# How to disable rule SP1516 in Settings.StyleCop?

Tags: c#, stylecop

I want to disable this style cop rule

> SP1516: Adjacent elements must be separated by a blank line.

How do I do that? What do I write in `Settings.StyleCop`?

Answer (score 4):

The following blog entry by Microsoft StyleCop gives you instructions on how to disable individual rules - [Enabling or Disabling StyleCop Rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/enabling-or-disabling-source-analysis-rules.aspx)

1. Right Click Project -> Source Analysis Settings
2. Click on the 'Rules' tab
3. Navigate to the particular rule you want to disable and uncheck it.
4. Click OK!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in Settings.StyleCop like this:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```