# Disable StyleCop warning SA0102 in Settings.StyleCop

Tags: stylecop

I want to suppress a particular StyleCop warning - SA0102 for the entire solution because StyleCop fails to parse [a particular C#6 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597877/interpolate-string-c-sharp-6-0-and-stylecop). How do I edit the file Settings.StyleCop to disable that warning?

It seems the syntax there is:

```
    <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustHaveText">
      <RuleSettings>
        <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
      </RuleSettings>
    </Rule>
```

But I don't know what rule name corresponds to SA0102.

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958321/how-to-disable-rule-sp1516-in-settings-stylecop) but the answer there describes how to use a GUI tool instead of editing the config file itself (with Notepad for example).

Comment: Try this please, `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "SA0102:GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustHaveText")]`

Comment: the rule corresponds to SA0102 should be in the stylecop settings file fyi

Comment: @UlugToprak That looks like C# code, not XML. Settings.StyleCop is an XML file.

Comment: Yes it is C# code indeed. You need to add this snippet to the `GlobalSuppressions.cs`

Comment: It doesn't work. Not suppressable.